# aws s3 sync command intermittently fails midway without error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Trying to sync buckets (one s3 bucket to other s3 bucket) in AWS S3 through Jenkins job
command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname1 s3://bucketname2 --exclude *snaps/**** --exclude '*.html' --no-progress
```

**Problem:**  The `aws s3 sync` command intermittently fails midway without error. Meaning, all the files are not getting synced to the destination bucket.

**Using below version:**

```
    aws-cli version:
        aws-cli/2.11.23 Python/3.11.3 Linux/5.4.0-1039-aws exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
    Jenkins version: 
        Jenkins 2.361.4
```

**Observations:**

- After printing around 4k lines to the stdout, sync is exiting with non-zero status code
- We enabled `--debug` flag with the above AWS CLI command and did not find any errors or hints about this abrupt stopping of the command
- The same commands works without any issues when we run this from local laptop.

Version using in local laptop:

```
aws-cli/2.7.16 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/21.5.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

Comment: It might be a Jenkins-related problem -- perhaps it times-out the command after a certain period? Or perhaps it is confused by `*snaps/****`, which seems like it should really be `'*snaps/*'` (including the quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object size might be the reason for faliure in sync operation. As per AWS documentation, the limit is 5 GB per object. If that's the case, you may have to look for multi-part upload.

Comment: The AWS CLI `aws s3 sync` command automatically uses multi-part upload for large objects.